# How to find the line which describes best a group of points?

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

So I've had this problem (not homework, don't worry) where I had to find the line that describes best a set of points if that makes any sense. I've come up with an algorithm which:

1. Calculates the slope between each pair of points, and gets an average
2. Using the average found in step 1, it finds the average interception with the y axis by going over all the points (y = mx + b, finds the b)
3. We check all the values of m,b which are in range of +-5, of the average found before, and then get the pair which the line has the smallest sum of distances to the points
4. We iterate however many times we like, by taking the result of step 3, and then checking for radius of +-0.5, and then +-0.05 etc.

I have two main questions / concerns to you if you can help:

- Is there a way to make this algorithm any more effective / accurate in a sense? And if so how?
- As I'm pretty new to OOP/C++, could you take a quick gander and see if I made any errors/bad calls in my code?

Thank you very much for your time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Point {
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    Point() //default
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    Point(double xAxis, double yAxis)
    {
        x = xAxis;
        y = yAxis;
    }
    double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    double getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
    void setX(double tx)
    {
        x = tx;
    }
    void setY(double ty)
    {
        y = ty;
    }
    double calcSlope(Point p2)
    {
        return (p2.getY() - y) / (p2.getX() - x);
    }
};
class Line {
private:
    double m;
    double b;
public:
    Line()
    {
        m = b = 0;
    }
    Line(double slope, double remain)
    {
        m = slope;
        b = remain;
    }
    Line(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        m = (p1.getY() - p2.getY()) / (p1.getX() - p2.getX());
        b = p1.getY() - p1.getX() * m;
    }
    double getSlope()
    {
        return m;
    }
    double getB()
    {
        return b;
    }
    void setSlope(double slope)
    {
        m = slope;
    }
    void setB(double bb)
    {
        b = bb;
    }
    double dist(Point p)
    {
        double d = (double)abs(m*p.getX() - p.getY() + b) / sqrt(1 + m * m);
        return d;
    }
    void avgLine(Point pArr[], int size)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
            {
                sum += pArr[i].calcSlope(pArr[j]);
            }
        }
        sum /= ((size)*(size - 1) / 2);
        double sumB = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            sumB += pArr[i].getY() - sum * pArr[i].getX();
        }
        sumB /= size;
        m = sum;
        b = sumB;
    }
    double sumDist(Point pArr[], int size)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            sum += this->dist(pArr[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int accuracy, size;
    double x, y, min, tmp;
    cout << "Please choose number of points:" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    Point *pArr;
    pArr = new Point[size];
    cout << "Please choose accuracy 0 < d < 5, accuracy is 10^(-d)" << endl;
    cin >> accuracy;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "X value:" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Y value:" << endl;
        cin >> y;
        pArr[i].setX(x);
        pArr[i].setY(y);
    }
    Line avgL;
    avgL.avgLine(pArr, size);
    Line minL = avgL, tmpLine;
    min = minL.sumDist(pArr, size);
    for (int i = 1; i >= pow(10, -accuracy); i /= 10)
    {
        for (double startM = avgL.getSlope() - 5 * i; startM <= avgL.getSlope() + 5 * i; startM += i)
        {
            for (double startB = avgL.getB() - 5 * i; startB <= avgL.getB() + 5 * i; startB += i)
            {
                tmpLine.setSlope(startM);
                tmpLine.setB(startB);
                tmp = tmpLine.sumDist(pArr, size);
                if (tmp < min)
                {
                    tmp = min;
                    minL = tmpLine;
                }
            }
        }
        avgL = minL;
    }
    cout << "The line is: y = " << minL.getSlope() << "x + " << minL.getB() << endl;
}
```

Comment: The second question is for Stack Overflow Code Review.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html

Comment: Realy cool: `(double)abs(m*p.getX() - p.getY() + b) / sqrt(1 + m * m)`. That is the right computation of the distance between the point and the line. So you are computing the perpendicular offset!! In place of computing the average slope, you may choose to find m and b by minimizing the sum of the square of this distance.

Comment: I believe the more usual term for "describes best" would be "[fits best](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_fitting)".

Comment: I can confirm that the variance/covariance method given by @moonshadow works very nicely.